# Open Another Workbook While Main Workbook Remains Active

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a workbook with links to another workbook. When I open the workbook with the links, I want it to automatically open the workbook the links refer to while the workbook with the links remains visible at all times. I have tried setting `ScreenUpdating` to `False`, but of course this has no effect as it only affects events within the active workbook. Please note that the workbook the links refer to needs to be accessible. Is this possible?

According to some sources, setting `ScreenUpdating` to `False` should do the trick, but the following code still displays the workbook for a moment before switching back:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Here’s my full code:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
  Dim sType As String
  Dim sFNType As String
  Dim sONFormat As String
  Dim objFSO As Object
  Dim objFolder As Object
  Dim objSubFolder As Object
  Dim sLastSubFolder As String
  Dim sDay As String
  Dim sMonth As String
  Dim iMonth As Integer
  Dim sYear As String
  Dim sOrderNo As String
  Dim iOrderNo As Integer
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim sFilename As String
  Dim tfOrderNo As String
  Dim iResult As Integer

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With
  If ActiveWorkbook.Name = Name Then
    frmOrderType.Show vbModal
    If Not iType = 4 Then
      Select Case iType
        Case 0
          sType = "Standard Orders"
          sFNType = "K"
          sONFormat = "0000"
        Case 1
          sType = "Promotion Orders"
          sFNType = "KP"
          sONFormat = "000"
        Case 2
          sType = "Test Orders"
          sFNType = "KT"
          sONFormat = "000"
      End Select
      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path & sType)
      Do Until objFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
          sLastSubFolder = objSubFolder.Name
        Next objSubFolder
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFolder.Path & "\" & sLastSubFolder)
      Loop
      iOrderNo = Val(Replace(Mid(sLastSubFolder, 7, 5), sFNType, "")) + 1
      sOrderNo = "SJ-" & sFNType & Format(iOrderNo, sONFormat)
      iResult = MsgBox("Create order with order number " & sOrderNo & "?", vbOKCancel, "Create Order")
      If iResult = vbOK Then
        tfOrderNo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OrderNo.txt"
        Open tfOrderNo For Output As #1
        Print #1, sOrderNo
        Close #1
      End If
      If Not iResult = 4 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        sDay = Format(Date, "dd")
        sMonth = Format(Date, "mm")
        sYear = Year(Date)
        If iType = 0 Then
          sPath = Path & sType & "\Orders " & sYear & "\Orders " & sYear & "-" & sMonth & "\KO " & sOrderNo & " " & sDay & sMonth & Format(Date, "yy")
        Else
          sPath = Path & sType & "\KO " & sOrderNo & " " & sDay & sMonth & Format(Date, "yy")
        End If
        MkDirFull sPath
        sFilename = "KO_" & sOrderNo & "_" & sDay & sMonth & Format(Date, "yy")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & "\" & sFilename & ".xlsm"
        Cells(11, 1).Value = "Order No: " & sOrderNo
        Cells(11, 7).Value = Date
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnFinalise").Visible = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path 'Open second workbook'
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on the requirement - 
Does the newly opened workbook have to be invisible to the user, or is it simply that the linking workbook remains active and the newly opened one can be visible, but in the background / not activated? Also - What Variatus said, please share some code / where you are stuck.

Comment: I updated my question. @RikSportel, as I stated, the newly opened workbook needs to be accessible, as in, the user should be able to switch to it via the task bar, but upon opening it, I don’t want any screen activity if possible.

Comment: Apart from moving `ThisWorkbook.Activate` inside the 'invisible' block, I don't see why this doesn't do what you want. Unless of course, the second workbook has a macro that reverts the `ScreenUpdating` setting within **it's** `Auto_Open`?

Comment: @CLR, the second workbook has no macros. As for moving `ThisWorkbook.Activate` inside the invisible block, doing so prevents switching back to the first workbook.

Comment: I think you need to post the *actual* code you're using in your `Auto_Open` then, as something else is going on.

Comment: I updated my question with the full code @CLR

Comment: You don't appear to declare iType, iResult, Name or Path. Are Name and Path functions?

Comment: Also: what's going on with `sPath = Environ(Path & sType & "\Orders " & sYear & "\Orders ".....` ? This is missing some code.

Comment: @CLR, `Name` and `Path` are just substitutions as this refers to very sensitive data and I want to avoid any possible exposure. `iType` is a global variable declared in another `Sub`, and `iResult` doesn’t seem to be producing any errors undeclared and the code works fine. I did go back and declare it though, but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: I can't see anything here that would cause an issue. `Screen Updating` should turn off all output to the screen, other than the status bar etc.

Comment: For some reason it doesn’t @CLR. I made a two new workbooks, added a module to one with the `Open` procedure and changed the `ScreenUpdating` property, but still the second workbook is displayed. Do you think only newer versions of Excel cause this? Have you tested it on your machine?

Comment: I have tried a bunch of approaches (Excel 2010 & 2016) and in all cases I do have a minimum amount of either turning the visibility of the entire Excel Application off or indeed having the newly opened workbook briefly visible. 
The shortest amount of visible time I achieved through an Application Wrapper and by hooking into the `WorkbookOpen` event.
The `ScreenUpdating` approach worked until Excel 2003, but in newer versions it will show the newly opened workbook instead of the one you're opening from, unless you place the `.Activate` outside of the screenupdating setting (so it flickers)